Lucid-Cardano --> TypeError: _this_walletAPI.experimental.on is not a function
Looking for a bit of assistance to understand what I'm doing wrong here..
I imported the Lucid and WalletAPI types using
import { Lucid, WalletApi } from 'lucid-cardano';

And am attempting to use it as such:
this.walletAPI?.experimental.on('accountChange', () => {

However when running my app in browser & trying to change wallets I get the following error: TypeError: _this_walletAPI.experimental.on is not a function..
Would anyone be able to provide a bit of insight on where I'm going wrong with this?
I'm working with Lucid v. 10.9.0
